# how to change label to red if number entered into textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, label

Simple problem. I have a label called lblName and a textbox called txtName. How do i make the labels font appear red if a number is entered into the textbox.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]   We dont need things like VB in the title, the tags take care of that

Comment: Have you done some basic research about your problem? And what is not clear that requires the help of the community to solve? Please show the code that creates the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub txtName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtName.TextChanged

    ' Gets the text from the text box.
    Dim text As String = txtName.Text

    ' Checks if the entered text is a number (Only numbers). 
    If IsNumeric(text) Then
        ' Change the label fore color to red.
        lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Else
        ' If the text is not a number, change the color back to black.
        lblNamge.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If

End Sub
```